# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection over http://

Tags: android

I am creating a project in android studio. I am getting this error while retrieving information from a sql server database. I am using .php files for database connection. On debugging I found that the following line is generating the error :

```
inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

On further inspection I have found that if I access my PHP files(which are used to query sql-server) over **https://** then the project is running well........but whenever I am accessing my php files over **http://**, the IOException is raised.

Comment: try catch the exception

Comment: ` java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{**.*.*.**:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=*.*.*.* cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ` -------------------------- here *.*.*.* is my server IP......I have traced the responsecode of the **HttpURLConnection** object.....it is returning 400.......

Comment: bro write the code inside try block and catch IOException using catch block

Comment: @Tirthadip . I am stuck at the same point .have you got any solution?? please post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a **space** in **query string** of url. Browser and Postman seem to detect and automatically correct this error.

I also have this problem. got solved by using **trim()** function in variables used in URL.